# terraform cdk equivalent for grantReadWriteData (available in aws-cdk)

Tags: terraform, cdktf, terraform-cdk

I am new to Terraform and also CDKTF. I have worked  with “regular” AWS CDK.

In AWS CDK you have methods like grantReadWriteData ( IAM principal example ). E.g. if you have a dynamodb table where you want to give a Lambda function readwrite permissions you can call something like this:
table.grantReadWriteData(postFunction);

Does anything like this exists on CDK TF or do we have to write those policy statements our selves and add them to a lambda function role?

i cant find much documentation in terraform for this

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything like that in terms of a fluent interface for libraries generated from a provider or module but I would definitely recommend looking into [iam-floyd](https://github.com/udondan/iam-floyd) for a similar type of fluent interface.

Answer (score 1):

Like this function `table.grantReadWriteData(postFunction);`
using AWS CDK L2 Construct Library [method](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/74318c7d22bfc00de9e005f68a0a6aaa58c7db39/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb/lib/table.ts#L407) to help you generate iam policy and attach policy at `lamdba` Function execute role.

The L2 construct library of CDKTF is not yet widespread for now.
So you need to define permission like this [way](https://github.com/cdktf-plus/cdktf-plus/blob/586aabad3ab2fb2a2e93e05ed33f94474ebe9397/packages/%40cdktf-plus/aws/lib/aws-lambda-function/index.ts#L52).

And if you want to use CDKTF to deploy/manage AWS Resource, maybe you can take a look https://www.terraform.io/cdktf/create-and-deploy/aws-adapter.